# Cannot use HtmlAgilityPack with multithreading

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, html-agility-pack

I'm using `HtmlAgilityPack` with `Parallel.Invoke`, in particular I have a class called `Table` which contains this implementation:

```
public class Table
{
   HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
  
   public void Foo1()
   {
       doc.LoadHtml("some html");
   } 

   public void Foo2()
   {
       doc.LoadHtml("some html");
   } 

   public void Foo3()
   {
        doc.LoadHtml("some html");
   } 
}
```

now the problem is that if I do this:

```
 Table table = new Table();

 Parallel.Invoke(
  () => table.Foo1(),
  () => table.Foo2(),
  () => table.Foo3());
```

I'll get:

> unexpected error

exception from HtmlAgilityPack, specifically on the third method. I can see that at the same time the object is used by the other two method (of course, I'm using Parallel).

If I call the method without `Parallel` all working good, how can I manage this issue?

*Stacktrace*:

> at HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection.Append(HtmlNode node) in C:\Users\Jonathan\Desktop\Z\zzzproject\HtmlAgilityPack\HtmlAgilityPack.Shared\HtmlNodeCollection.cs:line 321
> at HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode.AppendChild(HtmlNode newChild) in C:\Users\Jonathan\Desktop\Z\zzzproject\HtmlAgilityPack\HtmlAgilityPack.Shared\HtmlNode.cs:line 818
> at HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument.PushNodeEnd(Int32 index, Boolean close) in C:\Users\Jonathan\Desktop\Z\zzzproject\HtmlAgilityPack\HtmlAgilityPack.Shared\HtmlDocument.cs:line 1882
> at HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument.Parse() in C:\Users\Jonathan\Desktop\Z\zzzproject\HtmlAgilityPack\HtmlAgilityPack.Shared\HtmlDocument.cs:line 1424
> at HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument.Load(TextReader reader) in C:\Users\Jonathan\Desktop\Z\zzzproject\HtmlAgilityPack\HtmlAgilityPack.Shared\HtmlDocument.cs:line 706
> at HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument.LoadHtml(String html) in C:\Users\Jonathan\Desktop\Z\zzzproject\HtmlAgilityPack\HtmlAgilityPack.Shared\HtmlDocument.cs:line 752
> at SWP.Controllers.TableController.GetAttendanceTable(Int32 seasonId, Int32 competitionId, Int32 roundId, Int32 groupId)

Comment: A stack trace would have been more helpful.

Comment: @Aybe added, check

Comment: Look at this GitHub search, it'll give you a hint on what's going on : https://github.com/zzzprojects/html-agility-pack/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=Unexpected+error&type=

Comment: What do you expect to happen?  The object you are trying to use isn't able to be used in parallel like that, so you can't do what you want. We'll need to know more about why you are trying to do it to give a better answer about what to do instead.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to load html to the same HtmlDocument object asynchronously, almost no libraries are prepared to handle async modification of a non-static class, which is why (in some part) locking exists. I'm guessing every time you load HTML to the object it restarts the tree node data structure of HTML nodes and thus screws everything up.

If you want to parse/read the HtmlDocument object async then that would be one thing but you're actively writing to the HtmlDocument object which means out-of-order program execution could set a object property to null while also trying to iterating through that property.